# Live Thread in iOS like Thread in Java

Tags: ios, multithreading

I wonder if there is a construct in ObjectiveC espacially for iOS for Threading.
I like to create a class which implements the run()-Method and if I call start() for an instance of the class the instance worked as a new thread.

Is this possible?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of fact, yes there is. The class is called `NSThread`. You are free to create your own subclass and implement the `-main` method, which will be invoked on a new pthread when someone calls `-start` on an instance of your class.

Answer (score 1):

While there is NSThread as Kevin mentioned, really you should be looking at using blocks in a background GCD queue instead:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html

Blocks are much lighter weight and I find simpler to work with than threads.